# Best approach to update DB without effecting front end

Tags: database-design, oracle11g

I have a few tables where data to these tables would be populated from another Live data table (pulling data using OTA- Open Test Architecture from the live tables). Now I would have to do that periodically (3 or 4 time in a day) to update data in my tables.

Now my question is what is the best approach to do this? If I have to update tables that I use on regular basis, my plan is to delete current data and update that from Live tables, however when someone access the front end when data is been updated, they would get either no results or get wrong results. So how can we do this without effecting front-end but still update the data in my tables?

I am using Java/JSP/Hibernate/Scriptom/Groovy and Oracle DB.

P.S: I am new to all this stuff, so please correct me if this is not the right approach. Accessing Live DB is not an option for me. We will not be given access to Live data tables. If I have pull data using OTA and display directly in my Front end it would really slow.

Comment: That precisely what transactions are for. As long as you don't commit the intermediate changes, no other session (=transaction) will see them.

Comment: Thank you for replying...can you please explain me a bit more. Like I said it would not be few transaction but I would have to delete all the existing records from my tables and update with latest records from Live table.

Comment: The delete and insert would be exactly **one** transaction.

Answer (score 1):

All Oracle transactions have *at least* READ COMMITTED [isolation level](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2005/05-nov/o65asktom-082389.html). What that means is that the effects of a transaction are invisible to other transactions until it commits. Therefore, just encapsulate all the necessary operations in a **single** transaction, and the other transactions won't see the result of that until you commit (at which point the result is no longer partial).

In addition to that, writers never block readers, so other clients will be able to keep reading the old version of data while your transaction is still generating the new data.

BTW, Oracle also supports SERIALIZABLE isolation level, which might be more relevant for your needs - it would allow you to get a "snapshot in time" of the database when reading live tables.